# Software program for display analysis and benchmarking

Tags: c++, graphics, benchmarking, analysis

I aim to evaluate and do some sort of benchmarking on a display by writing a software program based on its framework and graphics library (in C++) to understand if the display meets the SW requirements. It's not clear yet what would be the final HW that the display runs on but for now it's on a demo board. Also, it's going to be connected to a real time system, so its input data is supposed to be updated very very fast (every 20ms).

1. What are the most important requirements for a display from SW perspective? (e.g. responsiveness, frame-rate)
2. How to test the requirements by implementing in a software program?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Software program for display analysis and benchmarking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120931/software-program-for-display-analysis-and-benchmarking)

Comment: do not post the same question twice